How to find xpath to be used for panos arbritary code execution?
I used burpsuite to retrieve the requests by intercepting it but I do not see xpath instead, i see xpathid.
I am not sure if the xpath is /system-general/login-banner, since it gave an error message:
fatal: [PALO-1]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"},"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (panos_type_cmd) module: command. Supported parameters include: api_key, cmd, dst, element, extra_qs, ip_address, new_name, ********, port, provider, username, where, xpath, xpath_from."}

This is the output:
POST /php/utils/router.php/SetupGeneralConfig.set HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.105
Cookie: PHPSESSID=2a10b012be897283a12fc44505c075fa; last-visited-page=device
Content-Length: 1483
Sec-Ch-Ua: "Chromium";v="125", "Not.A/Brand";v="24"
Content-Type: application/json
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.6422.112 Safari/537.36
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: "Windows"
Accept: /
Origin: https://192.168.1.105
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: https://192.168.1.105/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Priority: u=1, i
Connection: keep-alive

{"action":"PanDirect","method":"execute","data":["f175f15e174e2c47c2d4abbc26ff9222","SetupGeneralConfig.set",{"id":"","data":"<system-general><ip-address>192.168.1.105</ip-address><netmask>255.255.255.0</netmask><update-server>updates.paloaltonetworks.com</update-server><update-schedule><threats><recurring><weekly><day-of-week>wednesday</day-of-week><at>01:02</at><action>download-only</action></weekly></recurring></threats></update-schedule><timezone>US/Pacific</timezone><service><disable-telnet>yes</disable-telnet><disable-http>yes</disable-http></service><type><static/><dhcp-client><accept-dhcp-hostname>no</accept-dhcp-hostname><accept-dhcp-domain>no</accept-dhcp-domain><send-hostname>yes</send-hostname><send-client-id>no</send-client-id></dhcp-client></type><default-gateway>192.168.1.254</default-gateway><hostname>PA-VM</hostname><dns-setting><servers><primary>8.8.8.8</primary></servers></dns-setting><login-banner>hi</login-banner><server-verification>yes</server-verification><ntp-servers><primary-ntp-server><ntp-server-address>8.8.8.8</ntp-server-address></primary-ntp-server><secondary-ntp-server><ntp-server-address>8.8.8.4</ntp-server-address></secondary-ntp-server></ntp-servers><clock><displayValue>Thu Jun 20 2:48:35 PDT 2024</displayValue><date>2024/06/20</date><time>02:48:35</time></clock><multi-vsys>false</multi-vsys><urldb>brightcloud</urldb></system-general>","xpathId":"vsys","vsysName":"vsys1","fieldPaths":["login-banner"]}],"type":"rpc","tid":59}

This is what I have tried but to no avail:
- name: Set login banner
  panos_type_cmd:
    provider: '{{ provider }}'
    command: 'set deviceconfig system loginbanner Hi'
    xpath: |
      /config/devices/entry[@name='localhost.localdomain']
      /vsys/entry[@name='vsys1']
      /login-banner


It is literally telling you that command is not supported.  If you read the help file for the module you will see cmd.

@Squashman Ok it worked, but I aso had to change the xpath to /config/devices/entry[@name='localhost.localdomain']/deviceconfig/system. Any idea what is /deviceconfig/system?
Because when i applying this to another, xpath: /config/devices/entry[@name='localhost.localdomain']/mgt-config/password-complexity, element: '13 and it didnt work so i assume it isnt following the command executed within the terminal: set mgt-config password-complexity minimum-length 14 since they said the module isnt found

No idea.  I don't use PaloAlto.  I was just directing you to read the manual for the issue you had.  I have never used Ansible for anything related to PaloAlto. As I said in your other question, you should consider joining their Live Community. That site is specific to PalAlto and you will see many questions asked and answered about their Ansible Collections on their site.
